# Scrollable cotent with crossbrowser support including iOS

Tags: css, cross-browser, scroll, overflow

As we all know scrollable content i.e. CSS `overflow:scroll;` requires a hideous two finger scroll on iOS with no scrollbars. I have researched multiple ways to have a nice attractive iOS scroll but it's not good enough as they are all designed for iOS web apps.

So I am after a solution that does either of these things:

1. Detects apple mobile safari  and applies a javascript to all overflow:scroll elements.
2. Is a cross browser solution for scrollable content including iOS (would be nicest)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4). It's cross-browser compatible, and it also features a lite version.